# Set Icon on Statictext Control

Tags: c++, mfc

How to Set and Icon on a StaticText Control in MFC ?

I am trying with :

```
  static_cast<CStaticText*>(txt)->SetIcon(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDC_ICON));
```

The Line of code is executed. But the textcontrol is now showing the icon.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: In dialog editor, drop a picture control in to dialog. Then go to control's "Properties" window, change "Type" to "Icon"

Comment: I am not allowed to use the picture control :( so actually I have to set icon on a Static Text control

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I am not allowed". This is a static control. See also hypheni's answer.

Comment: there are some device related issues where I cant use picture control. Either I have to use cbutton or statictext . I found solt with the cbutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CButton* btn
    btn->SetIcon(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_IMG));
```

Comment: You should not use `LoadIcon` — https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853121/383779

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you dropped a Static Image/Icon control over your dialog instead of Static Text control.

You can verify from resource file:

```
BEGIN
    CTEXT           "",IDC_STATIC_ICON1,10,84,300,20
    ICON            "",IDC_STATIC_ICON2,102,137,20,20
END
```

First one is Text type and second is Icon. You should use second one.