# Changing Window icon using the windows api in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to change the window icon, however the assertion in main.cpp (hIcon != 0) always fails, I have an Icon.ico (128x128) file in the root directory of the project solution but still receives an error when executing. Any suggestions

main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <crtdbg.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
      HINSTANCE hInstance = ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
      HICON hIcon = LoadIcon (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDI_ICON1));
      _ASSERTE (hIcon != 0);
      SendMessage (hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
      return 0;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
      return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
      PostQuitMessage (0);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return (DefWindowProc (hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
}


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevIns, LPSTR lpszArgument, int iShow)
{
  TCHAR szClassName[] = _T("Template");
  TCHAR szWindowName[] = _T("Template");
  WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
  MSG messages;
  HWND hWnd;

  wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wc.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BTNSHADOW;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  
  _ASSERTE(RegisterClassEx (&wc) !=0);
  
  hWnd = CreateWindowEx (0, szClassName, szWindowName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
      CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
      HWND_DESKTOP, 0, hInstance, 0);
      
  _ASSERTE(::IsWindow(hWnd));
  
  ShowWindow (hWnd, iShow);
  while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage (&messages);
    DispatchMessage (&messages);
  }

  return static_cast<int>(messages.wParam);
}
```

resource.h:

```
#define IDI_ICON1                       101
```

resource.rc:

```
#include "resource.h"
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "Icon.ico"
```

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return?

Comment: @PaulSanders it returns "port (null ) can't be opened" It's weird because the window changes its icon but I'm not sure why the error message is displayed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852864/loading-an-icon-in-windows-program

Perhaps this might help?

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN:

> LoadIcon can only load an icon whose size conforms to the SM_CXICON
> and SM_CYICON system metric values. Use the LoadImage function to load
> icons of other sizes.

Check if both

`GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);`
`GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);`

returns 128 (since you are loading 128x128 icon). If not use LoadImage function.

Comment: that "can only load an icon whose size conforms to the SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON system metric values" stuff is about 25+ years outdated :)